# .net application won't run on developer machine but works on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

First of all I want to apologise if this question was answered before, I've searched but I didn't find anything [maybe didn't searched correctly]

I've developed a very simple console application, which doesn't do anything else but display a random number from 2 integers.

Code:

```
int miNumber;
int mNumber;
bool ok = false;

try
{
    miNumber = Convert.ToInt32(minNumber);
    mNumber = Convert.ToInt32(maxNumber);
    ok = true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Only digits allowed!");
    Console.ReadKey();
    ok = false;
}

if(ok)
{
    // Generate
    var x = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Generated number from {0} and {1} is {2}", miNumber, mNumber, x.Next(miNumber, mNumber)));
}
```

However, this application works on:

- Developer machine if runned with visual studio [debug]
- Another PC with .NET 4.0 installed.
- My laptop

This application does not work on:

- My own computer. If I copy test.exe in another location, it won't run.

I'm sure that I got .NET 4.0 since I run on Windows 8.1, I even tried to install it again but it says I already have it. [Anyways the Visual Studio could'nt make application in .net 4.0 if there wasn't the framework installed]

I've checked Event Viewer and I ain't see anything displayed such as error or something inputted by the system at the moment the application was run.

I tried:

- Running the application from CMD [Stucks] [Screenshot added] [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI31w.png)
- Running the application from explorer.exe [Stucks and displays the loading cursor like forever]

If I close the console application displayed, the executable is still running. I tried to kill it from CMD using 'taskkill /f /im test.exe' with highest privilege available [Killing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESPSh.png)  however, I'm receiving an error at my second try.

The executable is still there, I can't delete or move the exe until I restart the machine.

Thanks for any help provided because I really don't get it what's the issue here.

Comment: Please show the entire program, and let us know what your references are. Please detail what the "error on the second try" is.

Comment: Do you reference any other DLLs? Any 3rd party tools? If so, you need to install them as well. Also, the error message might give us a hint.

Comment: Virus affected system ?, happened to me once!

Comment: Are there any other .dll files in the bin directory where you got the .exe after Visual Studio compiled it?  If so, those need to be copied too.

Comment: I also imagine it might help you to see **where** it gets stuck. If you print to the console as you go, you might see where it gets halted. Then, it's much easier to get to **what** that's wrong.

Comment: We've been having this kind of question asked all week.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4QyPzk0.png these are the references / Whole program: http://i.imgur.com/R54xaaQ.png - No error displayed, it just doesn't run at all. However in Visual Studio works: http://i.imgur.com/EbWfZ7B.png

Comment: @HansPassant Lol, indeed. I disabled Avast and the application run succesfully.

Comment: What happens if you write to the console before you enter the try-catch? Can you see that? Also, if you comment out read-keys - does it change anything?

Comment: @HansPassant Case to give some insight on why Avast can stuckify such a simple code piece like the OP's?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'm guessing its trying to run it in a sandbox that doesn't have enough access to the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @HansPassant https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant

The problem is from Avast Antivirus.

I've disabled Avast shields and the application is working properly.

> I really don't get why avast doesn't like .NET Frameworks so much but, at least is a temporary fix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it could be some kind of `anti virus application` that's blocking your application.

**Update** Too late :D